# React and dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, chai

I'm trying to test a react component with jest, this look like :

```
class UserOnSamePageAlert extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            connected_users: []
        };

        // subscribe to channel to know if a user is on the same page
        this.onSamePageChannel = new OnSamePageSubscription({
            current_user: sessionStorage.getItem('current_user'),
            url: props.urlToSubscribe,
            onUpdate: this.onUserAction,
        });
    }
... more code here ...

}
```

And my OnSamePageSubscription Component :

```
export default class OnSamePageSubscription extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ... more code here ...
    }
    ... more code here ...
}
```

This work fine, but I don't think that's the good way for testing purpose.
I think that I have to inject the OnSamePageSubscription object, to unit test.

**My questions are :**

- Which way to inject is the best way in react (best practice or a lib)
- Is there a good library to mock object ?
- Or maybe I don't have to inject in order to mock ?

Comment: You'll need to add the other component to the test file. How you mock them is up to you, but remember, you should be able to test these in isolation. Don't try to test the functionality of 1 component inside another.

Comment: jest [can mock modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) injected through `import` so you don't need additional DI tool/platform.